# itgenuty530: The document property 'INVANTIVE_REPOSITORY' can not be accessed since Excel is busy calculating

Tags: invantive-control, exact-online

When opening a spreadsheet with Exact Online formulas and Invantive Control blocks I receive the following error:

```
itgenuty530: The document property 'INVANTIVE_REPOSITORY' can not be accessed since Excel is busy calculating.
```

It also says:

```
HRESULT: 0x8001010A (RPC_E_SERVERCALL_RETRYLATER)
```

After clicking a number of times on OK, the data is retrieved. How can I avoid this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you open a spreadheet with Exact Online formulas, Excel will start calculating values in the background. However, you are not yet logged on to Exact Online completely. For the calculation Excel and the Control add-in need access to the document property 'INVANTIVE_REPOSITORY'. And this fails since you are not yet fully set up to calculate formulas.

There is currently no solution, only a workaround:

- First start Excel.
- Then log on to Exact Online.
- Then open the spreadsheet.

When following these steps, it works fine.